# How to apply polynomial equations for each row?

Tags: r, loops, polynomials

I have a dataset where the headers are the names of the drivers , the last column is the result of the polynomial equation, and all other data in the dataset indicates to what power the drivers need to be taken to, to form the equation. For example, using a mock dataset:

| Driver_1 | Driver_2 | Driver_3 | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 | 0 | 10 |
| 1 | 0 | 3 | 4 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 7 |

I want to create and store:

1. Driver_1^0 + Driver_2^2 + Driver_3^0 = 10
2. Driver_1^1 + Driver_2^0 + Driver_3^3 = 4
3. Driver_1^2 + Driver_2^0 + Driver_3^0 = 7

In reality, my dataset is much larger with many more drivers and many more rows. Is there a way to automate the creation of these polynomial equations by looping over all rows in a dataset to create all polynomials equations needed?

Perhaps I need to use `lm` with `poly` terms to create this but not sure how I can automate the creation of all the equations needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a matrix `m` with the exponents,

```
m
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    2    0
[2,]    1    0    3
[3,]    2    0    0
```

and exploit vectorization by exponentiating `dat` with `m` and taking the rowsums.

```
dat$result <- rowSums(dat^m)
dat
#   Driver_1 Driver_2 Driver_3 result
# 1        5        5        4     27
# 2        6        3        1      8
# 3        2        3        4      6
```

You probably confused the exponents with your data in your example, so I used new data.

---

*Data:*

```
m <- matrix(c(0, 2, 0, 
              1, 0, 3, 
              2, 0, 0), 3, byrow=TRUE)
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(matrix(rpois(9, 3), 3, dimnames=list(NULL, c('Driver_1','Driver_2',   'Driver_3'))))
```